# Can't pass params from navigation.navigate

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, expo, react-navigation

I am not able to pass the `itemId` param to RestaurantInfoScreen with this code:

```
onPress={() => {
  navigation.navigate('RestaurantInfoScreen', { itemId: 86});
}}
```

and getting the params in the `RestaurantInfoScreen` with this code:

```
const { itemId } = route.params;
```

But defining the `initialParams` like this works:

```
<RestaurantStack.Screen
   name = "RestauranInfoScreen"
   component={ResturantInfoScreen}
   initialParams={{ itemId: 46 }}
/>
```

I tried many possible ways but could not pass the params from the `navigation.navigate` function.

These are some of what I have tried:

```
navigation.navigate('RestaurantInfoScreen', { itemId: 86});
navigation.navigate('RestaurantInfoScreen', { params: { itemId: 86 },});
```

How do I pass the params correctly.

Many Thanks

Comment: I figured out that the screen was nested in a stack. So navigating to the stack then to the screen works perfectly.

Comment: ```
navigation.navigate('RestaurantInfoScreen', {
      screen: 'RestaurantInfoScreen',
      params: { itemId: 86 },
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Home.js

```
import { Button, StyleSheet, Text, TextInput, 
    View } from 'react-native';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
  
const HomeScreen = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const goToMessageScreen = () => {
    navigation.navigate('Message', {
      message,
    });
  };
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>GeeksforGeeks</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Enter your message here"
        value={message}
        onChangeText={(text) => setMessage(text)}
        style={styles.input}
      />
      <Button title="Submit" 
        onPress={goToMessageScreen} color="green" />
    </View>
  );
};
  
export default HomeScreen;
```

Detalis.js

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import { useRoute } from '@react-navigation/native';
  
const Detalis = () => {
  const route = useRoute();
  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{route.params.message}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};
  
export default Detalis;
```

hope this will help you to find your error

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `useRoute()` and `useNavigation()` to get those params. They should really update the docs! Check out user19534405's answer for an example.